# PHP form with text and image inputs using adminlte - DropZone js

Tags: javascript, php, file, upload, dropzone.js

I am using a template from adminLTE(https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/pages/forms/advanced.html) you can see it at the end of the page, I want to just upload images first and pass the image name as one of the input text elements to my main form to pass them when submitted the final form.

1. But dropzone is restricting to use the form tag to upload photos, we cannot use form isnide another form
2. I have no other option than this

Could anyone help me with the idea on how to implement this in PHP or using js and html? or any reference?

Comment: Will you consider triggering dropzone upload page as a modal popup form ?

Comment: No as per the requirement and workflow it's the only way I have to go through it

Answer (score 0):

This automatically uploads images without submitting the form.

```js
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, {
    url: "upload.php", // this url change. upload.php only image upload.
    thumbnailWidth: 80,
    thumbnailHeight: 80,
    parallelUploads: 20,
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    autoQueue: true, // and this change true.
});
```